# Scala regex pattern match of ip address

Tags: regex, scala

I can't understand why this code returns false:

```
      val reg = """.*(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}).*""".r
      "ttt20.30.4.140ttt" match{
        case reg(one, two, three, four) =>
          if (host == one + "." + two + "." + three + "." + four) true else false
        case _ => false
      }
```

and only if I change it to:

```
  val reg = """.*(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}).*""".r
  "20.30.4.140" match{
    case reg(one, two, three, four) =>
      if (host == one + "." + two + "." + three + "." + four) true else false
    case _ => false
  }
```

it does match

Comment: I know regex, but have no clude about scala. But it seems you're using 3 double-quotes there - I assume that gives you one quote which then becomes part of the pattern you are searching? No, that can't be - otherwise you 2nd case also wouldn't match. Well, sry - seems I can't help - but at least let me assure you that the rx is fine ;-)

Comment: no, trupple quites alow for raw strings in scala,  that can even contain " literally without escaping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your variant

```
def main( args: Array[String] ) : Unit = {
  val regex = """.*(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}).*""".r
  val x = "ttt20.30.4.140ttt"

  x match {
    case regex(ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4) => println(ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4)
    case _ => println("No match.")
  }
}
```

matches, but not as you intend. Result will be (0,30,4,140) instead of (**20**,30,4,140). As you can see `.*` is greedy, so consumes as much input as it can.

e.g. `ab12` could be separated via `.*(\d{1,3})` into

- `ab` and `12`
- `ab1` and `2` .... this is the variant chosen, as `.*` consumes as much input as it can

### Solutions

1. Make `.*` reluctant (and not greedy), that is `.*?` so in total

   ```
   """.*?(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}).*""".r
   ```
2. Precisely define the pattern before the first number, e.g. if these are only characters, do

   ```
   """[a-zA-Z]*(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}).*""".r
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **reluctant quantifier** rather than **greedy quantifier**:

```
val reg = """.*?(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}).*""".r
```