# Validation of IP address in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to validate the IP address in scala. I have implemented the method but I am seeing some errors.

Can anyone look into it and suggest if they have better solution. I am not trying to implement functionally.

```
 def validIPAddress(IP: String): String = {

       var isValidIP = true
       if(IP.contains(":")) {  
            var numbers= IP.split(":")   //create an array
            if (numbers.length!=8) return "Neither"        
            for (n <- numbers) {
                if(n.length = 0 or n.length > 4) return "Neither"    
                else {
                    for (m <- n) { 
                        if(!m in "0123456789abcdefABCDEF") return "Neither"
                    }
                }
            }
            return "IPv6"
       }
       else if(IP.contains(".") {     //192.168.1.1
              nums = IP.split(".")
              if(nums.length!=4) isValidIP = false  //Array.length
              else {
                for (a <- nums) {
                  println(a)
                  try {
                    var intA = a.toInt
                    if(intA <=0 || IntA > 255) {
                      isValid = false
                    } 

                  } catch (NumberFormatException e)  {
                    case e: Exception => None
                  }
                }

                if(isValid == true) {
                  println("Valid IP")
                } else {
                  println("Invalid IP") 
                }


              }
       } return "IPv4"

       else {
         return "neither"
       }

       }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala regex pattern match of ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008914/scala-regex-pattern-match-of-ip-address)

Comment: You can try: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html

Comment: Definitely: regexps, no `var`s, no `return`s, and some sane flow control and error reporting logic (these `return`s after brackets looks like something almost certainly wrong at the first glance).

Comment: You've [already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60496856/4993128). If the answers weren't good enough to be accepted, please explain why. (For that matter, none of your questions on SO have an accepted answer. If you don't like the help you're getting here, why do you keep coming back?)

Answer (score 3):

You might not intend to implement funcationaly but there is no need for imperative code in your example at all and `return`s and `var`s cause some serious issues when it comes to reading the intend of the code.

I would rewrite the code to something like this

```
sealed trait IP extends Product with Serializable
object IP {
  final case class V4(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) extends IP
  final case class V6(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int, f: Int, g: Int, h: Int) extends IP
}

val ipV4 = """(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})""".r
val ipV6 = """([0-9a-fA-F]+):""".r

def validIPAddress(ip: String): Either[String, IP] = {
  def parseV4(s: String) = {
    val i = Integer.parseInt(s)
    if (0 <= i && i <= 255) Right(i) else Left(s"$i is not a valid IPv4 number")
  }
  def parseV6(s: String) = Integer.parseInt(s, 16)

  ip match {
    case ipV4(a, b, c, d) =>
      for {
        a1 <- parseV4(a)
        b1 <- parseV4(b)
        c1 <- parseV4(c)
        d1 <- parseV4(d)
      } yield IP.V4(a1, b1, c1, d1)
    case ipV6(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) =>
      // technically speaking this isn't exhausting all possible IPv6 addresses...
      // as this regexp would ignore e.g. ::1 or ::
      Right(IP.V6(parseV6(a), parseV6(b), parseV6(c), parseV6(d), parseV6(e), parseV6(f), parseV6(g), parseV6(h)))
    case _ =>
      Left(s"$ip is neither V4 nor V6 format")
  }
}
```

to make it easier to follow and debug errors, though as I checked this implementation is NOT really conforming to what IPv6 does, as some tuning around regexp usage would be necessary. As a matter of the fact, I would prefer to avoid rolling my own solution altogether if I couldn't afford some time for writing down like 15-20 test cases.

So, unless there is a reason to implement your own validator I would delegate that task to some library which already tested handling corner cases.

If you have to, however, do the following things:

- don't use `return` - in Scala it does something different than what you think it does
- don't use `var`s unless you're optimizing - the way you use them have nothing to do with optimization (`isValid` is never used, so why override it? and other vars are never modified)
- don't use string for everything because that is asking for trouble on its own (e.g. `"neither"` and `"Neither"` - should the caller use `.equalsIgnoreCase` on your code to check results?)
- start with tests written basing on specification. While I translated your code it fails valid IPv6 addresses. If I skipped the requirement that Iv6 is fixed size, it  would be even shorter to:

```
sealed trait IP extends Product with Serializable
object IP {
  final case class V4(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) extends IP
  final case class V6(values: List[Int]) extends IP
}

val ipV4 = """(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})""".r
val ipV6 = """([0-9a-fA-F]*)((:[0-9a-fA-F]*){2,})""".r

def validIPAddress(ip: String): Either[String, IP] = {
  def parseV4(s: String) = {
    val i = Integer.parseInt(s)
    if (0 <= i && i <= 255) Right(i) else Left(s"$i is not a valid IPv4 number")
  }
  def parseV6(s: String) = if (s.isEmpty) 0 else Integer.parseInt(s, 16)

  ip match {
    case ipV4(a, b, c, d) =>
      for {
        a1 <- parseV4(a)
        b1 <- parseV4(b)
        c1 <- parseV4(c)
        d1 <- parseV4(d)
      } yield IP.V4(a1, b1, c1, d1)
    case ipV6(head, tail, _) =>
      val segments = head +: tail.substring(1).split(':')
      Right(IP.V6(segments.map(parseV6).toList))
    case _ =>
      Left(s"$ip is neither V4 nor V6 format")
  }
}
```

which handled more correct cases but is still far from ready. So if you can - avoid doing it yourself and use a library.